# DotCloud: Application Not Responding

Tags: node.js, mongodb, dotcloud

I am trying to see dotcloud actually work and I have not been able to get it to work. I cloned and pushed https://github.com/sebm/MongoPop.git I added a dotcloud.yml

api:
    type: nodejs
mongo:
    type: mongodb

because it didn't seem to push without it and then I tried to visit the url and I got an Error Application not Responding. I should get something like http://2a6ad2ac.dotcloud.com/

I would like to use dotcloud but have never been able to actually see it work.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you add a `dotcloud.yml` and a `supervisord.conf` file.

The repo you are referring to had them, and for some reason removed them. see this commit.

https://github.com/sebm/MongoPop/commit/5aea02dd88b282b23d367157a44de21416485afa

Here is what they should look like

**`dotcloud.yml`**

```
api:
   type: nodejs
mongo:
   type: mongodb
```

**`supervisord.conf`**

```
[program:node]
command = node app.js
directory = /home/dotcloud/current
```

Add those to your project, add and commit the files to the repo, and then re-push. If it doesn't work, please update your question with the log output from the command.

Answer (score 0):

The Application Not Responding error can sometimes be caused by [dotCloud's health checks](http://docs.dotcloud.com/tutorials/more/cloud-health-check/).  Make sure you respond with a 404 or 200 status code to `/CloudHealthCheck`  Otherwise, dotCloud removes your services from rotation assuming that something bad has happened.